# Instagram follower count.. Why is there no reliable way?

Tags: python, django, instagram

A task I've been wanting to finish for awhile is to have a dashboard where you'll have a little Instagram logo with a number which is your follower count.

This means I need the latest follower count everytime the user loads the page. I have had it working before with Beautiful Soup but it was heavy and ended up getting blocked.

Why is there no way to simply get the follower count of an Instagram page (not necessarily my own)?

Here I have my latest attempt. I did not know you can add `/?__a=1` to the url and get JSON data about the account!

This works if I request the page in the browser but as soon as I implement it with `requests` I get a 429 status code (too many requests)

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/nike/?__a=1')
print(response.status_code) # 429
# print(response.json()) # Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score -1):

From what you are trying to do is that you are trying to access a secure endpoint API without the credentials from the code so you are unable to access it.

If you try to debug it you will find the content with the login page as content

[image: Login page debug]

```
import requests

cookies = {} #place your session cookies into this
response = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/nike/?__a=1', cookies=cookies)


print(response.status_code)  # 429
print(str(response.content))
# print(response.json()) # Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```